# Encapsulate a NavLink component and style it with Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am trying to create a menu with hyperlinks from the `react-rounter-dom` library component `NavLink`
and style it with styled component

I Created a component called `Link` which is where `NavLink` is so you don't repeat this same line of code multiple times, then pass this component to styled component to inherit its properties so you can apply styles to it.

but the styles are not being applied to my component

**NavLink**

```js
import { NavLink as NavLinkReactRouterDom } from "react-router-dom";

const Link = function ({ to, children, ...props }) {
  return (
    <>
      <NavLinkReactRouterDom
        {...props}
        className={({ isActive }) =>
          // console.log(isActive)
          isActive ? "is-active" : undefined
        }
        to={to}
      >
        {children}
      </NavLinkReactRouterDom>
    </>
  );
};
export default Link;
```

**sidebarStyled.js (css)**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import Link from "./NavLink";
//    NavLink
export const Prueba = styled(Link)`
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;

  &.is-active {
    color: green;
  }
`
```

**Sidebar**

```js
const Sidebar = function () {
  return (
    <SidebarContainer>
      <LogoContainer>
        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
      </LogoContainer>
      <h1>Sidebe Here</h1>
      <Divider />
      <Menu>
        <NavList>
          <NavItem>
            <Prueba to="/">
              <LinkIcon icon="typcn:home-outline" />
              Inicio
            </Prueba>
          </NavItem>
        </NavList>
      </Menu>
    </SidebarContainer>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `className` prop of the styled component, `Prueba` isn't passed through to the component it's attempting to style, the `NavLinkReactRouterDom` component. Or rather, it *is* passed implicitly when the props are spread into it, but `NavLinkReactRouterDom` is overriding and setting it's own `className` prop.

```
const Link = function ({ to, children, ...props }) {
  return (
    <>
      <NavLinkReactRouterDom
        {...props} // <-- styled-component className pass here
        className={({ isActive }) => // <-- overridden here!
          // console.log(isActive)
          isActive ? "is-active" : undefined
        }
        to={to}
      >
        {children}
      </NavLinkReactRouterDom>
    </>
  );
};
```

## Solution

The solution is to merge the styled-component's `className` prop with the active classname used for the `NavLinkReactRouterDom` component.

Example:

```
const Link = function ({ to, children, className, ...props }) {
  return (
    <NavLinkReactRouterDom
      {...props}
      className={({ isActive }) =>
        [className, isActive ? "is-active" : null].filter(Boolean).join(" ")
      }
      to={to}
    >
      {children}
    </NavLinkReactRouterDom>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit encapsulate-a-navlink-component-and-style-it-with-styled-component]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use Prueba, instead of Link. since you inherit the Link component, applied custom CSS and store it in the variable named Prueba.

hence import it in the sidebar.js file and use it there

refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-smoke-1bflsh?file=/src/App.js

add

```
import 'Prueba' from sidebarStyled.js'
```

change

```
....
<Prueba to="/">
   <LinkIcon icon="typcn:home-outline" />
    Inicio
</Prueba>
....
```

Comment: Excuse me, I copied the element that was not, I edited the post.

Rename the component to `<Prueba>...<Prueba/>`

And it still doesn't apply the styles